# Using Authorization Header Basic with fetch and suppress browser password prompt

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I want to use fetch requests in javascript with the Authorization header. It works, but Chrome shows me a prompt message to save the credentials. I don´t use any forms.

```
let config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic aaaa:xxxx`
        )}`
      },
      ......
    };

const response = await fetch(url, config);
```

I want to suppress this prompt. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you look on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) you see that 
 "the request contains a header field where credentials is the base64 encoding of id and password joined by a single colon (:)."

So you need to transform your username:password to base64

You can achieve this with the btoa function

btoa('username:password')

For my example the result is : "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to write that I am still using base64 to encode it.

Comment: if I start a fetch request to another server , chrome still shows a prompt